# Boolean Expression evaluation . Couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write an evaluator for a Boolean expression . Here type of evalAExp :: AExp-> Maybe Int (i.e. Arithmetic expression evaluator). Arithmetic evaluator is working for me.

In Boolean Evaluator I want the type to be :: BExp -> Bool. 
While compiling I get an error like ``` Couldn't match expected type ``Bool' with actual type ``BExp'
    In the pattern: Eq a1 a2
    In an equation for ``evalBExp':
        evalBExp (Eq a1 a2) = evalAExp (a1) == evalAExp (a2) ```

The end types of a BExp should be Bool.

How should I be declaring my BExp in this case. Is there a better way of going about it.

```
data BExp = Eq AExp AExp | Lt AExp AExp | Gt AExp AExp | ELt AExp AExp| EGt AExp AExp | And BExp BExp | Or BExp BExp | Bool

evalBExp True = True
evalBExp False = False
evalBExp (Eq a1 a2) = evalAExp (a1) == evalAExp (a2)
```

Here in `evalBExp (Eq a1 a2) = evalAExp (a1) == evalAExp (a2)` I am comparing Just Int == Just Int and the resultant is a Bool. What should I be doing? I think there is a problem in the data BExp declaration itself for me.

Any Help

**EDIT :**

I changed my code to something like this.

```
data BExp = Eq AExp AExp | Lt AExp AExp | Gt AExp AExp | ELt AExp AExp| EGt AExp AExp | And BExp BExp | Or BExp BExp |Boolean Bool

evalBExp (Boolean True) = True
evalBExp (Boolean False) = False
evalBExp (Eq a1 a2) = (evalAExp (a1)) == (evalAExp (a2))
```

So I changed the type to Boolean Bool. Is this a better way of declaring a type . Why not simply Bool as earlier. Is there a better way to do this.

**Entire Code**

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List
data AExp = Var Char | Value Int | Add AExp AExp | Mul AExp AExp | Sub AExp AExp
data BExp = Eq AExp AExp | Lt AExp AExp | Gt AExp AExp | ELt AExp AExp| EGt AExp AExp | And BExp BExp | Or BExp BExp |Boolean Bool
data AssignExp = AExp Char |  BExp Char
data Statement = AssignExp | While BExp Statement
type Env   = M.Map Char Int

env = M.fromList[('A',1),('B',2),('C',3)]

evalAExp :: AExp -> Maybe Int
evalAExp (Value x) = (Just x)
evalAExp (Var x) = M.lookup x env
evalAExp (Add a1 a2) =do
  v2<-evalAExp a2;v1<-evalAExp a1
  return (v1+v2)
evalAExp (Sub a1 a2) =do
  v2<-evalAExp a2;v1<-evalAExp a1
  return (v1-v2)
evalAExp (Mul a1 a2) = do
  v1 <-evalAExp a1;v2 <- evalAExp a2
  return (v1*v2)

evalBExp (Boolean True) = True
evalBExp (Boolean False) = False
evalBExp (Eq a1 a2) = (evalAExp (a1)) == (evalAExp (a2))
```

Comment: Probably you should put all of your relevant code here ? How is `AExp` and `evalAExp` defined ?

Comment: Sorry about that . I couldn't find a way to point to the problem I had while explaining, so I added that part. I am a bit bad at expressing myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your suspicion, "I think there is a problem in the data BExp declaration itself", is correct. What you've written doesn't mean what I suspect you hope it does. The error is at the far right end (as errors often are) so I had to scroll to find it. Using more vertical space, let's see.

```
data BExp
  = Eq AExp AExp
  | Lt AExp AExp
  | Gt AExp AExp
  | ELt AExp AExp
  | EGt AExp AExp
  | And BExp BExp
  | Or BExp BExp
  | Bool
```

And it's the last that is the big problem. It's harder to spot because although you tell *us*, "I want the type to be :: BExp -> Bool", you do not tell the compiler. If you had done the decent thing and communicated your intention by writing an explicit type signature, the error report might have been more helpful. Your program begins

```
evalBExp True = True
```

and that is enough to convince the typechecker that the intended type is

```
evalBExp :: Bool -> Bool
```

because `True :: Bool`. When line 3 shows up with

```
evalBExp (Eq a1 a2) = evalAExp (a1) == evalAExp (a2)
```

suddenly it wonders why you're giving `evalBExp` a `BExp` instead of a `Bool`.

Now, I suspect that you have the impression that your final clause in `BExp`

```
| Bool
```

makes `True :: BExp` and `False :: BExp`, but that's not what it does at all. Instead, you will discover that you have a nullary data constructor `Bool :: BExp` whose name is coincident with the datatype `Bool` but lives in an entirely separate namespace. I believe your intention is to embed the values of `Bool` into `BExp` silently, but Haskell does not allow such subtle subtyping. To achieve the intended effect, you will need a constructor which explicitly packs up a `Bool`, so try

```
data BExp
  = ...
  | BVal Bool
```

and

```
evalBExp :: BExp -> Bool
evalBExp (BVal b) = b
...
```

to get closer to your plan.

You are, of course, free to use the name `Bool` for the `BVal` constructor, and so write

```
data BExp
  = ...
  | Bool Bool
```

where the first `Bool` is a data constructor and the second is a type constructor, but I would find that choice confusing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining out types to me so wonderfully. I will keep that in mind to embed end types everytime.